# Freeboard: Indicator Light widget not working

Tags: javascript, freeboard

I'm trying to compare two timestamps and if it's greater than x seconds difference, indicate "offline".  Here is what I have in the js editor of the widget:

```
// Example: Convert temp from C to F and truncate to 2 decimal places.
// return (datasources["MyDatasource"].sensor.tempInF * 1.8 + 32).toFixed(2);
console.log("Checking Time Difference")
var timediff = (new Date) - datasources["ConsentDS"].Timestamp 
console.log(timediff)
if timediff > 1 * 60 * 1000 {
    return 1
} else {
    return 0
}
```

The indicator always stays "online" even when the difference should be greater than 30 seconds.  It's not even writing to the console like I expect.

I can't find any documentation so I'm not even sure if I should be returning 1 or true or elephant :(

Comment: If this is just vanilla Javascript, shouldn't your calls to `console.log` include parentheses for the syntax to be valid? E.g., `console.log("Checking Time Difference")`

Comment: ayayay, I just finished a VBScript project.  Luckily (I guess?) I changed it and it still doesn't work.

Comment: Do you at least see the log statements in the console now? If not, that would seem to indicate that this code isn't even getting called.

Comment: I am not seeing the statements in the log.

Comment: Without knowing anything else about freeboard, it sounds like that's the first problem you need to solve -- making sure that your code is actually being run. Without that, returning `1` or `0` or `elephant` won't make much of a difference.

Comment: For the record, somehow it processes these widget scripts as a transaction, I guess. I don't understand it, but if you have an error at the very end you won't see a console.log at the beginning.  You also see no errors in the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So most of my problem was javascript syntax, as @Donut and probably others noticed immediately.

Here is the working version:

```
var ts = new Date(datasources["ConsentDS"].Timestamp).getTime();
var ms = new Date().getTime();
var d = ms - ts;

if (d > 5 * 60 * 1000) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

If the current time minus the timestamp on the data is more than 30 seconds (30000 milliseconds) then it returns 0 which is the "OFF" status on the indicator widget.

Comment: Glad you were able to figure it out, sorry I couldn't be more help! Thanks for posting your answer here in case others have the same problem.

Comment: Nonsense, my javascript is so rusty I don't think anyone could have helped me but myself :)  I genuinely appreciate the effort!